# Character theory question.

Tags: group-theory, characters

Let $\chi$ be a nontrivial irreducible character of finite group $G$, and $G$ has odd order. Then, $\chi$ isn't equal to  $\bar \chi$.

Comment: Hi! Can you add some more context to your question? Definition of $\bar\chi$ would make it clearer.

Comment: $\overline\chi$ is the character $g\mapsto \overline{\chi(g)}$ where $\chi\colon G\rightarrow \mathbb C^*$. The OP should show us his work/thoughts on the question, though.

Comment: Are you familiar with the determinant of a character?

Comment: I'm not very good in determinant and I think we don't need determinant to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Hint: using the orthogonality relations, show that if $\chi \neq 1_G$ (the trivial character) and $\chi=\bar{\chi}$, then $\chi(1)=2\alpha$ for some algebraic integer $\alpha$.

Comment: I remembered that $\chi(1)$ divides $|G|$, but I could not remember why. Is it trvial ?

Comment: @mesel Not quite trivial. One does a computation showing that the quotient is an algebraic integer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:hımm, thank you.